# Store a user profile in iOS app so that it's always accessible

Tags: ios, datastore

I want to create a user that the app fetches from disk every time the app is opened, and written every time it is closed. I want the data from the user, such as `NSString` name, along with some other variables, to be accessible from any other point in the app.

There will only be one user so it is kind of a "global" variable. Also, if the user class includes pointers to data structures like `NSMutableDictionary`, or another instance of `NSObject`, are there any precautions I need to take?

I want to learn the best way to implement this, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Create a class to represent your user

2) Have that class implement the `NSCoding` protocol

3) Use `NSFileManager` to create or open a file as necessary

4) Use that file to restore / store the user class. (Its easy using the `NSCoding` protocol)

5) Make the user class owned by your model which exposes the data in the user class, or make the user class a singleton (The first is much better).

You should be able to find examples / tutorials if you search how to store stuff using `NSCoding`

Comment: Can you explain how I make the user class owned by the model? I'm confused as to what would be the model that exposes data

Comment: Research the MVC pattern (model view controller)

Comment: Okay so my view controller has a user object, and I load my user from file in the app delegate on launch or terminate, how do I pass my user from the delegate to my view controller (or multiple), or do I group all of them into a nav controller and assign my user to that?

Answer (score 2):

[NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is your friend. It meets your requirements to be accessible from any other point in the app.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't use NSUserDefaults if the data contains dynamic data structures, which it does.

Comment: @Piepants will you please explain it , why NSUserDefaults is not good option for storing dynamic contents.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an UserObject extended by NSObject. Use a `Singleton Pattern` so you always have the same object inside every class.

Then you could just save every variable inside `NSUserDefaults` by using a specific `key`. 
If you want to save the whole object inside `NSUserDefaults` you need to include the `NSCoding` in the interface

```
@interfaces User : NSObject <NSCoding>
```

and use the methods `initWithCode:` and `encodeWithCoder`:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    self = [super init];
    if( self ){
        strName = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"name"];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder{
    [aCoder encodeObject:strName forKey:@"name"];
}
```

for un / archiving do it this way:

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:userObject];

UserObject *user = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

if you want some more information you [can read all about it here](http://bit.ly/stackDecoder).

Answer (score 0):

Use keychain in case there is private user data to store.
In most cases Martin's answer is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

NSUserDefaults is a great option. You can access it from every point on your app, save and extract data anytime and store most of the things you'll probably need.

To save:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDef = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDef setObject:userDictionary forKey:@"userData"];
[userDef synchronize];
```

To Extract:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDef = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSDictionary *userDictionary = [userDef objectForKey:@"userData"];
```

You can save your data on your AppDelegate's

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application;
```

And Extract on:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application;
```